# why i couldn't connect to internet using ZTE made reliance in HSD mode?

Tags: wireless, usb-modem, zte

I am trying to connect to the internet with a Reliance Netconnect+ made by ZTE.

The manufacturer provided a driver disk to install it, but I couldn't make the install programme work, and whenever I tried I see that "this driver is not in good condition" and I still couldn't connect in HSD mode.

I am not having any problem while connecting using 1X or hybrid mode.

Please can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Install their Cross platform UI deb file. And then you can set it up into HSD Mode.
You can get deb file in their CD (Virtual CD Drive which comes when connected into windows without installing drivers)

Comment: Could you explain me how to do that?

Comment: @suraj jungade yeah i tried that but when i tried to install "it says that package is not in good health"